# Dynamically changing the language of columns labels in VueJS

Tags: plugins, vue.js, internationalization

I implemented a multilanguage support for the website. Using VueJS and VueI18n. There are 3 pages - home, registers and messages. The problem is in messages, where there is a dynamically rendered table - vue-good-table. While being on this page(with the table) if I click on the buttons for changing languages, everywhere the languages is being changed dynamically, but not the labels and placeholders of the table. If I go to one of the other pages and comeback to the table, the labels and placeholders are updated correctly. Can you help me make it change while I am on the same page?

I was wondering if beforeMount() would help in this situation?

***main.js***

```
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n'
import {messages} from './locales/bg_en_messages'

Vue.use(VueI18n)

const i18n = new VueI18n({
  locale: 'bg', // set locale
  fallbackLocale: 'bg',
  messages // set locale messages
});

Vue.prototype.$locale = {
  change (lang) {
    i18n.locale = lang
  },
  current () {
    return i18n.locale
  }
};
```

***Messages.vue:***

```
<vue-good-table
  :columns="columns"
  :rows="items"
  :paginate="true"
  :lineNumbers="true">
</vue-good-table>

<script type="text/javascript">
  export default {
    data(){
      return {
        items:[],
        columns: [
          {
            label: this.$t("columns.date"),
            field: 'changeddate',
            type: 'String',
            filterable: true,
            placeholder: this.$t("columns.date")
          },
          {
            label: this.$t("columns.userChange"),
            field: 'userchange',
            type: 'String',
            filterable: true,
            placeholder: this.$t("columns.userChange")
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

***App.vue***

```
<div style="padding: 10px; width: 99%;">
  <ui-button @click="changeLang('bg')">
    <img src="../src/assets/images/skin/Flag1.png" v-bind:alt="home" height="15" width="25"/>
</ui-button>
  <ui-button @click="changeLang('en')">
    <img src="../src/assets/images/skin/Flag2.png" v-bind:alt="home" height="15" width="25"/>
  </ui-button>
</div>

<script>
    export default {
      name: 'Localization',
      methods: {
        changeLang: function(newLang){
          this.$locale.change(newLang)
        }
      }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that the data that's changing is nested inside an object itself and your template only listens to changes to that parent object and not for its children (your language data). So even if that changes, your view wont notice it. If you use data from your translation directly in the template using the template syntax, the data will re-render automatically because that is not nested(that's why it probably works everywhere else).

Now of course you can't do that in your table's case, because your table component accepts nested data only, **so the workaround would be to use a computed property for your columns**, instead of putting them into your component's data. This way all changes will be mirrored to your component.

Simply change your component like that and you should be good to go:

```
export default {
    data(){
      return {
        items:[]
      }
    },
    computed: {
      columns () {
        return [
          {
            label: this.$t("columns.date"),
            field: 'changeddate',
            type: 'String',
            filterable: true,
            placeholder: this.$t("columns.date")
          },
          {
            label: this.$t("columns.userChange"),
            field: 'userchange',
            type: 'String',
            filterable: true,
            placeholder: this.$t("columns.userChange")
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Philip Feldmann ! Worked like a charm. Sorry for the dumb question tho :)

Comment: @Decrux You are welcome, don't be afraid to ask. I just want to point out that I got my explanation why this didn't work was wrong, the actual reasoning was that your data was nested. Either way, computed fixes the problem.